# Opencart вывод цены в произвольном месте

Tags: opencart

Подскажите, как при наличии ID товара вывести его цену в произвольном месте (статья, блог)? Расширение Shortcodes (https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=15550) не умеет саму цену, или полную карточку, или название.